# Flutter Получение url изображения из Firebase CloudFirestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

нужна помощь с бд.
Не подгружается картинка, используется firebase Cloud Firestore. В img_url храниться ссылка вида */uploads/instrument-na-test.png*

```
List<Widget> getData(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((document) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text(
      document["title"],
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    subtitle: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Image.network("http://site${document["img_url"]}"), 
      Text("  ${document["body"]}", softWrap: true),
      Text(
        "\nДата тействия акции ${document["date_str"]}",
        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 15),
      ),
    ]),
  );
}).toList();
```

}

**Выводит ошибку**
I/flutter (20697): Another exception was thrown: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://site/uploads/instrument-na-test.png
I/flutter (20697): Another exception was thrown: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://site/uploads/cd79e8d227db00b44d1d7f4145fc487a.jpeg

**Пробовал**
Картинки не подгружаются на экране, хотя по ссылкам из консоли путь получается правильный.
Добавлял   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" в манифест, но это не дало результата.
Пробовал CachedNetworkImage

***Спасибо***

Comment: [Способы как можно решить проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172791/flutter-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform). А вообще, у firebase `https` должен быть по идее.

Comment: Изображения размещены не в firebase storage, а на сайте где протокол http. android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" должен был бы решить эту проблему, но нет

Comment: Ну добавьте ssl на сервер, Let's Encrypt например. И не будет у вас проблемы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** мне не помог. Установка ssl сертификата решила проблему полностью. Всем спасибо